# Convert a string to an object argument for summarize function in R

Tags: r, dplyr

[image: m6 dataframe]
I am implementing a loop over column names of a dataset. The code is as follows

```
for(i in 14:20){
  col_name <- colnames(m6[i])          #m6 is the name of the dataframe see the image for reference

  mean_group1 = paste(paste(col_name, "group1", sep="_"),"= mean(",col_name, "[group == '1'])",sep="") #here [group == '1'], group is the name of a column in m6 dataframe  
  mean_group2 = paste(paste(col_name, "group2", sep="_")," = mean(",col_name, "[group == '2'])", sep="")
  mean_group3 = paste(paste(col_name, "group3", sep="_")," = mean(",col_name, "[group == '3'])",sep="")

  formula_f_2 <- as.formula(paste(mean_group1, mean_group2,mean_group3, sep = ""))

  pl <- m6 %>%
  group_by(CHILD_ID)  %>%           #CHILD_ID is the name of  a column which is being grouped 
  summarize(formula_f_2)
}
```

The problem with this code is it is giving me an error. What I think is it is maybe due to me passing a string as an argument to Summarize function which it is not able to understand. When I implement the code without the loop that is by writing the segment for every case it runs fine the code which runs fine. The code which works is as follows:

```
#This is the code which I wrote for when i is 20 i.e. for colnames(m6[20])

pl <- m6 %>%  group_by(CHILD_ID)  %>%  summarize(mean_group1 = mean(A_SD_zscore[group == '1']),
        mean_group2 = mean(A_SD_zscore[group == '2']),mean_group3 = mean(A_SD_zscore[group == '3']))
#
#Here m6 is a dataset on which I am applying group and summarize function
#Here A_SD_zscore is colname(m6[20])
```

The output that I get when I write the single sengment of correct code.

[image: Output that I want]

Comment: You current code which is working can be changed to `m6 %>%
  group_by(CHILD_ID, group) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(A_SD_zscore))` to simplify. As far as the question is concerned can you create a a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and show expected output based on that so that it is clear what you are trying to do?

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you for your comment. So I can't change the code as in the thing which I am trying to do is different from what I will be able to accomplish from your code.

Comment: Let me see if I can create a reproducible example.

Comment: @RonakShah Can you please have a look at it once again. I have added some information.

Comment: The post isn't really reproducible, screenshots aren't helpful. We need data to be shared in copy - paste-able format possibly using `dput`. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) gives information on how data needs to be shared. I am assuming this is the reason why nobody (including myself) were not able to help you.